# How to create a treemap from a text file

Tags: java

I have the following content of a txt file:

```
 Some text I would like not to inclcude

#id: col1, name, money\

  2017-01-02, Michael,  200 \
  2017-01-01, Tobias,   300 \
  2017-02-03, Susan,    400 \
  2017-05-04, John,     200 \
     ...     ...    ...
 Some text I would like not to inclcude
```

I would like to create a Treemap and put `col1` as my key:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;


    class earnings
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("example.txt"));

            TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split("\t");
                map.put(columns[0],columns[0]);
            }

            System.out.println(map);
        }
    }
```

Out put with `Some text I would like not to inclcude`:

```
    {=,  2017-01-01,  Tobias,   300 \= 2017-01-01,  Tobias,   300 \,  
 2017-01-02, Michael,  200 \= 2017-01-02, Michael,  200 \,  2017-02-03,  
 Susan,    400 \= 2017-02-03,  Susan,    400 \,  2017-05-04,  John,     
 200 \= 2017-05-04,  John,     200 \,  Some text I would like not to 
 inclcude= Some text I would like not to inclcude, Some text I would 
 like not to inclcude=Some text I would like not to inclcude}
```

Out put without `Some text I would like not to inclcude` still has some duplication:

```
    {=,  2017-01-01,  Tobias,   300 \= 2017-01-01,  Tobias,   300 \,  
   2017-01-02, Michael,  200 \= 2017-01-02, Michael,  200 \,  2017-02-
  03,  Susan,    400 \= 2017-02-03,  Susan,    400 \,  2017-05-04,  
  John,     200 \= 2017-05-04,  John,     200 \}
```

How can I manage to create a treemap which has `Some text I would like not to inclcude` and looks as:

```
{ 2017-01-01, Tobias,  300 \ 2017-01-02, Michael, 200 \ 2017-02-03, Susan, 400 \  2017-05-04,  John,     200 \}
```

Or at least without duplication

Comment: What are the keys you want in your map? I mean, what are `String` and `String`?

Comment: I would like to have the `col1` key as `String` and the other part is `String`as well

Comment: And the other part?

Comment: You are not splitting your string properly.`columns[0]` is actually the whole line "2017-01-02 Michael 200 \".

Comment: @tsolakp yes, I could not figure out how to do that beeing a java rookie

Comment: Try using a split matching to whitespace? But that wouldn't work if column 2 has spaces.

Comment: Ok, each columns has `,`to separate. sry. I update the question!

Comment: Your original file has 'text to be excluded': How do you identify this?  Is it true that a valid row contains three fields: Date, String name, int value, and that any other line should be discarded?

Comment: The original file has much more columns and begins with the line I included in the question. Above `id: col1, name, money\ `   is   `Some text I would like not to inclcude` and below the last relevant row. But the setup is identical. The data type may vary as well. But I think, based on this example Im able to generalize it.

Comment: When you process input, and the file has extra information to be excluded, you need processing rules.  It sounds like:  1)  Read line by line until you reach 'Some text I would like not to inclcude' 2) That triggers valid records  3) Until you hit another 'Some text I would like not to inclcude' then you stop processing.  Is this true?

Comment: Yes, that is the case here!

Comment: OK.  Your code has this flaw. You always put to the Map. You need to work towards processing rules.  A boolean like 'canProcess' and set it to true when you finally read the trigger word. Only when true do you add to Map.  But even then, you must check for the trigger to stop processing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting unwanted data into the set is because your file input is complex, and you need processing rules to establish what parts of the file are valid.  You have stated that you have a start trigger, and a stop trigger.

The states of processing are:

1. Not Ready
2. Ready (after reaching the start trigger) - In this state read into your Map
3. Finished (after reaching the stop trigger)

It is not clear what value goes into the map (the key is the date).  For now, I have concatenated the name and money value: Please fix this if this is not correct.  Note you needed to split the String using a ",";

This code manages those states, and ensure that any data going into the Map is valid data (in between the start and stop triggers)

```
public class Earnings {

final static String START_TRIGGER = " Some text I would like not to inclcude";
final static String STOP_TRIGGER = " Some text I would like not to inclcude";

enum ProcessingState {
    NOT_READY,
    READY,
    FINISHED;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("Example.txt"));

    TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    ProcessingState processingState = ProcessingState.NOT_READY;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine() && processingState != ProcessingState.FINISHED) {

        String lineToProcess = scanner.nextLine();

        if (processingState == ProcessingState.READY && lineToProcess.startsWith(STOP_TRIGGER))
            processingState = ProcessingState.FINISHED;

        if (processingState == ProcessingState.READY) {
            String[] columns = lineToProcess.split(",");
            map.put(columns[0],columns[1]+", "+columns[2]);
        }

        if (processingState == ProcessingState.NOT_READY && lineToProcess.startsWith(START_TRIGGER))
            processingState = ProcessingState.READY;


    }

    System.out.println(map);
}

}
```

I tested with your data, and this produced:

```
{  2017-01-01= Tobias,    300 \,   2017-01-02= Michael,   200 \,   2017-02-03= Susan,     400 \,   2017-05-04= John,      200 \}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "2017-01-01, Tobias,   300 ";
String[] split = s.split(",");
if (split[0].trim().matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")) {
    System.out.println(split[0].trim());
}
```

In your method, you can do:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
    if(columns[0].trim().matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")        
    map.put(columns[0],columns[0]);
}
```

Comment: I thought about using this approach, but given the complexity of the file, there is no guarantee that this won't add bad data.  This match may occur before the start of processing indicator.

Comment: Lot of dates in `Some text I would like not to inclcude` ?

Comment: I am only going by what the poster said in a comment - that there may be data prior to (or after) that phrase, and in that case that data may contain a date.  Otherwise I agree with you.